# Why I have this extra space when I am adding UIView.xib?

Tags: ios

Why I have this extra space when I am adding UIView.xib into an UIView used as a container for an UIViewController. I am using Storyboard for UIViewController , xcode 9.2 ,. The blue area is the containerView

[image: Screen]

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //Same problem if I am calling this into a Button action
        calendarView = ClassName(frame: containerView.frame)
        containerView.addSubview(calendarView)
    }   
}

class ClassName: UIView{
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)        
    commonInit()
}

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit(){        
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NibName", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)

    contentView.frame = bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]


 }
}
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `contentView` is not declared, so your code can never compile. Show _real_ code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question "What is this" is: it's the distance between the `containerView` and the top of its superview.

Think about it. You have this line:

```
calendarView = ClassName(frame: containerView.frame)
```

But the next line will be:

```
containerView.addSubview(calendarView)
```

But you cannot set a view's frame in terms of its superview's *frame*. They are in two different coordinate spaces! The result here is that the `calendarView` is offset within its superview exactly as the the `containerView` is offset within *its* superview. Often the result would be far worse even than that.

You mean *bounds*.

```
calendarView = ClassName(frame: containerView.bounds)
containerView.addSubview(calendarView)
```

Now the `calendarView` will exactly fill the `containerView`.

(Of course you will still have issues later, because you not positioning things using autolayout. But at least this will give you the *initial* position that you are expecting.)